# Is the union of a closed and an open set closed?

Tags: real-analysis

Given an open set A, and a closed set B.
Is the union, $A\cup B$ also closed?

I’m not too sure how to prove/disprove this statement. Any help would be appreciated.

(I’ve seen a similar question but that looked like it required some topology knowledge; I’m solving this problem from the point of view of someone taking introductory real analysis)

Comment: $A=(0,1)$ and $B=[1,2]$.

$A$ is open, $B$ is closed but $A\cup B=(0,2]$ wich is neither open nor closed.

Comment: With problems like this, it's frequently a good idea to look at "degenerate" cases...Like $A\subset B$ or $B\subset A$.

Comment: Other degenerate cases to look at would be things like $A = \emptyset$ or $B = \emptyset$, or alternately try $A$ or $B$ is the whole space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. Take $A = [-1, 1]$ and $B = (-2, 2)$. Then $A \cup B = (-2, 2)$ which is an open set.

Answer (score 0):

The union could be open, closed or neither depending on the sets.

$$(-1,1)\cup [-2,2] = [-2, 2]$$

$$[-1,1]\cup (-2,2) = (-2, 2)$$

$$[-1,3]\cup (-2,3)= (-2,3]$$